# Blazor component routing for dynamic pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I came up with a strange task.

I have 3 Blazor components with dynamic pages, and do not understand how I can release it.

Q: How can I can reduce the number of lines @page "/"... @page "/...{section}"

Or maybe who know how I can exclude some urls like @PageExlude "..."

[HomePage.razor]

```
@page "/"
@page "/{section1}"
@page "/{section1}/{section2}"
...
@page "/{section1}/{section2}/.../{sectionX}"

.... CODE ....
```

[AdminPage.razor]

```
@page "/admin/"
@page "/admin/{section1}"
@page "/admin/{section1}/{section2}"
@page "/admin/{section1}/{section2}/{section3}"
@page "/admin/{section1}/{section2}/{section3}/{section4}"

.... CODE ....
```

[PreviewPageContent.razor]

```
@page "/admin/previewPage/{PageId:int}"
@page "/admin/previewPage/{PageId:int}/{Revision:int}"

.... CODE ....
```

for people who do not understand the task:

```
when I call -> Result
localhost/ -> HomePage.razor
localhost/admin/ -> HomePage.razor
localhost/previewPage/1 -> HomePage.razor
localhost/Identity/Account/Manage/Index -> HomePage.razor
```

Comment: Ok i have solution )))

https://github.com/GoranHalvarsson/SitecoreBlazor/tree/master/Foundation/BlazorExtensions/CustomBlazorRouter

Answer (score 2):

Catch-all route parameters are another way to handle this.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0
[image]